# Search for inactive user?

Tags: support, search

How do I look for answers/question of an inactive user, for instance **user121799**

I obviously tried the search bar with

[image: ![enter image description here]

I am surprised I get only 16 results for a former active user (like Marmot).

When I then try **121799**

[image]

I get more results but the query seems to go through text and not user.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369989/how-can-we-find-all-the-posts-of-a-deleted-user-from-its-user-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the user profile is removed, you'll have to search via the *display name*. So, "John Doe" with user ID 123456 that has been deleted will have a display name `user123456`. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1531254/posts-from-user-by-display-name?UserId=user121799) displays all posts for `user121799`.

[image]

You can enter a different user display name (highlighted above) and click Run Query to see a list of the posts.